# The mean and deviation of two sets with unequal lengths

Tags: random-variables, ratio

I want to determine the mean and the deviation (e.g., mean squared deviation or mean absolute deviation) the ratio of two independent sets (J/K) with unequal lengths.

J = {x_1, x_2, x_3}
K = {y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4}

I can get the means of both sets and get the ratio of the means fine, but how do you get deviation? Can I use the delta method?

An alternative idea was determining the mean and the deviation of the set of pairwise ratios: {x_1 / y_1, x_2 / y_1, … x_3 / y_4}

However, there are some values in either set that deviate strongly so then the set of pairwise ratios would also deviate strongly so I don't think this is completely fair.

What are your thoughts? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the ratio of two sets"?

Comment: Hi Paul, Id want to summarize J/K as a random variable with a mean and deviation

Comment: "summarize" *what* as a random variable? **What is** $J/K$? How are you defining it?